# Prove that a group is non-cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I have some problems with an exercise of group theory. It sounds like this:

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^2q^2$ with $p$, $q$ prime numbers, $p$ is odd, $p<q$. I know that $G$ doesn't contain a normal subgroup of order $q$ but contains a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup $H$. I must prove that $H$ is non-cyclic.

Comment: Cyclic groups contain normal subgroups of all orders dividing the group's order (they're abelian).

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't proove that $H$ is not cyclic. Even if we assume that $H$ is cyclic (and abelian because it is cyclic or because is of order $q^2$ with $q$ prime), and so it contains a normal subgroup of order $q$, I can't say that I obtain a contradiction because that subgroup could be not normal in $G$.

Comment: It proves the group is non abelian, which is sufficient.

Comment: I don't understand, $H$ is abelian since is of order $q^2$.

Comment: No, I said that the group $G$ contains a normal Sylow q-subgroup $H$ but doesn't contain normal subgroups of order $q$.

Comment: Yes, but if it's cyclic then there is only one subgroup of order q, so...

Comment: And why it couldn't be normal in G?

Comment: There is only one subgroup of order q in a cyclic group of order $q^n$, but the Sylow theorem says they're all contained in a maximal Sylow, i.e. $H$.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is cyclic, then $H$ contains a unique (hence characteristic) subgroup of order $q$. This implies that the subgroup of order $q$ is normal in $G$, a contradiction.